# JXcore throw error when add task

Tags: jxcore

I got this error when I was trying to use `jxcore.tasks.addTask` function in my program.

```
undefined:1
function (){}
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at gcc (_jx_tasks.js:130:24)
    at process.<anonymous> (_jx_tasks.js:425:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at process.__makeCall (node.js:420:23)
```

I'm not sure that `jxcore.tasks.addTask` function makes it or not, it's only happened when I declare a new prototype for Array. Simple code below in my program throw this error:

```
Array.prototype.doSomething = function(){};
jxcore.tasks.addTask(function () {}, {}, function () {});
```

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Yep, this looks like a bug. I was able to reproduce it. It's been noted down and will be handled, however have you considered posting it to jxcore [issues](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/issues)?. You'll get better feedback and fixing progress updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be [fixed](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/commit/11baebe9f311a91c05501cadc62961ca701f9fc0) now.

You haven't mentioned, which JXcore version you are using, but if it's 0.2.3.7 and below (judging by the error output syntax), then you should switch to current open source version available on [github.com/jxcore/jxcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) where the fix was applied.